# Make linux look like windows 8

Tags: themes

I have seen tutorials about making linux look like windows 7, but is there a tutorial about making it look like windows 8.

Comment: are you free kick mind ? use windows 8 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not currently, but me and my team are working on a project with he UX metro start menu for windows 8 and the exact theme of windows 8 for ubuntu 12.04LTS and above. We should hae it finished by the end of June. When we are finished i will put a link up to the themes and instructions in this conversation on ubuntu.com