# How to get metro interface in Ubuntu?

Tags: themes

Is there any way to get Windows 8 metro UI on Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you'd like to have Metro UI?

Comment: Nobody's developed one so far.

Comment: Same question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/269126/make-linux-look-like-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no Metro UI shell developed for Ubuntu.

However, there is a [Windows 8 GTK theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=158721) on Gnome Look.

[image]

Sorry for off-topic answer but Windows can be made to look like Ubuntu -

[image]

Comment: +1. How can I unsee this monstrosity! My eyes! My eyes! :D